# jQuery Timepicker - Every 15 minutes

Tags: jquery, time, timepicker

I am using jQuery Timepicker as follows:-

// Time Picker Function

```
$(function() {
    $('#time').timepicker({ 'scrollDefault': 'now','timeFormat': 'H:i', stepMinute: 15 });

  var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 15;
  var date = new Date();  //or use any other date
  var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);

  $('#time').timepicker('setTime', rounded);

});
```

In the options object, I've tried setting `interval: 15` and `stepMinute: 15`. By default, the dropdown shows the time in 30 minute intervals. I'm trying to change that to 15 minute intervals. Is there a way I can change this?

Comment: Give us a link to the plugin. Each have different usage and options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the GitHub site, there is no `stepMinute` option. I did, however see a step option. That's most likely what you're looking for and will solve this issue

> **step**
>   The amount of time, in minutes, between each item in the dropdown. Alternately, you can specify a function to generate steps dynamically. The function will receive a count integer (0, 1, 2...) and is expected to return a step integer.
>   default: 30

https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

Edit: It's important to include these two files

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out there. I was working on the fiddle myself but had a hard time getting it to work.

Comment: Helped me as well...  $(function () {
        $('[type="datetime"]').datetimepicker({ step: 15});
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"].date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
        startDate: dateNext,
        minuteStep : 15
    });
```

minuteStep is proper solution. Tested in Bootstrap DatetimePicker.